# Which services/daemons/etc are responsible for (auto)mounting on Linux?

Tags: systemd, mount, kde, automounting

I have a `Makefile` ([source here](https://github.com/raspi/RaspberryPiArchLinux/tree/2bcfeab2ad8e0e1b91fd7dbebe6387240d56f5e1/rpi4/1splitpartitions)) which uses [Raspberry Pi 4 Arch Linux](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-4) [.tar.gz image](http://os.archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-rpi-4-latest.tar.gz) and generates `/boot` FAT and `/` (root) EXT4 partition images to be used later for generating SD card or for further splitting the root partition image into smaller partitions.

I'm running it on Manjaro (Arch based) with KDE.

The problem is that usually the temporary partition mount point(s) needed to generate the partition images from the tarball seems to get stuck and will not unmount with `umount`. There seems to be some automounting magic going on with systemd and maybe some with KDE also.

There were many more stuck mountpoints before, but I found these environmental variables:

```
UDISKS_AUTOMOUNT_HINT:=never
UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY:=1
UDISKS_SYSTEM_INTERNAL:=1
UDISKS_AUTO:=0
UDISKS_IGNORE:=1
```

These seemed to help and less mount points were left hanging. Usually it is the `/boot` one which just sticks around. So is there any other variables or `mount` parameters or something so that `umount` will be respected and mount points actually will be removed? Or could you generate everything within chroot/fakeroot?